# Matching first regular expression floating point percent?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match the perecent value in a string:

```
Starting task, 13.73 % (11.17 fps, avg 14.66 fps, ETA 00h03m53s)
```

The problem is my regex works but it matches all three floating point values:

```
\d*\.\d+%?
```

I get three values back:

11.17
14.66

- 13.73
- 11.17
- 14.66

I only want to match 13.73.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your pattern is that it will match a number followed immediately by an optional percent sign. Since the percent is not a required part of the pattern, other numbers match it just fine.

You can try this pattern (note that `\s*` means zero or more white space characters):

```
\d*.\d+\s*%
```

This will return `13.73 %`. If you don't want to include the `%` sign, use a group:

```
(\d*.\d+)\s*%
```

And then extract the the relevant text.

Alternatively, you could use a lookahead:

```
\d*.\d+(?=\s*%)
```